# Antimalarials as confounding variables in a prevalence study

Tags: epidemiology, confounding

I am performing a multi-level logistic regression analysis of cross-sectional survey data, and I am curious as to whether "**taking antimalarials**" is a confounding variable in the following situation:

The exposure is "**sprayed insecticide in the house**", and the outcome is "**infected with malaria**".

Given the complex relationship between "taking drugs", being "infected with malaria" (the outcome) and "spraying insecticide" (the exposure), I am wondering if I should control for "taking drugs" as a confounder: as curative drugs, malaria causes a person to take the drugs; as prophylactics, they are preventative, as is insecticide spraying. Also, after getting malaria, a person is more likely to start taking preventative measures,i.e, taking prophylactics or spraying insecticide.

So, I am confused, are "drugs" confounding the relationship between exposure and outcome?

Drugs and insecticide both seem to be associated.
Not spraying could certainly cause infection with malaria.
Taking prophylactics could certainly prevent you from being infected with malaria.
Malaria could certainly cause you to take the curative drugs.
Yet drugs are not on the causal pathway in any of these paths.

Confused!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi Christian - Given the complex relationship between "taking drugs", being "infected with malaria" (the outcome) and "spraying insecticide" (the exposure), I am wondering if I should control for "taking drugs" as a confounder: as curative drugs, malaria causes a person to take the drugs; as prophylactics, they are preventative, as is insecticide spraying. Also, after getting malaria, a person is more likely to then start taking preventative measures,,e, taking prophylactics and spraying insecticide. So, I am confused, are "drugs" confounding the relationship between exposure and outcome?

Comment: Do I need to control for them in my regression model?

Comment: Please add all necessary information to the question rather than just writing it as comment.

Comment: You have a cross-sectional design, so you have no way of knowing if people using the insecticides or drugs were using it as a prophylactic or treatment after they are diagnosed with malaria. E.g., if a person has malaria and using either insecticides or drugs, you don't know if he has already been using it or not. In a strict sense, there are bidirectional effects between your exposure and outcome, and also between insecticides and drugs. As a result, you really can't measure the true direct or total effect: https://postimg.cc/yJQYCXNt

Comment: @The_old_man - Thanks for this (and for taking the time with the diagram). So, in this sense, would it be advisable to "explore" the role of "drugs" as a confounding variable? In other words, running the model, both with and without drugs included. Is that a logical approach?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the details of your study: inclusion and exclusion criteria, your setting, etc. to be able to establish a robust relationship between the variables. In your specific case, I suggest you refer to similar published studies to see if its feasible to consider drugs as confounding.